# Update appcache manifest file version automatically

Tags: performance, html, caching, html5-appcache

I have enabled [application cache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) for my web application. Now i need to make sure on every time i generate the war or deploy the application, cache manifest file's version get updated automatically. So that the browser will load the content from the server instead for cache after every deployment.

So let me know if there is any way to update version automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the manifest dynamically. With PHP, JSP, or any other server side language you want/could use. Without information about the used/preferred language I couldn't provide a practical sample.

Or you let your build script append the lin while creating the war.